# Join data from hourly and 30 minute tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with data every hour:

[image]

and a table with data every 30 minutes:

[image]

I would like to join these two tables (by date) to get batVolt and TA in the same table and repeat the values for batVolt for the 30 minutes between the hour.

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like the datatypes are most likely datetime?

Comment: I had tried a similar query than what M.Ali suggested below.  I do have some interesting behavior with this query though.  
The query that M.Ali suggested works. It runs perfectly on SQLFiddle  [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1531/4] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1531/4) with the subset of my data, but when I execute the query on my server I get this: [http://i.imgur.com/hTGYMwA.png](http://i.imgur.com/hTGYMwA.png) My tables have 6.5 million rows (array3) and 400 thousand (ARRMet). Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: OK, for anyone who might be having the same problem, as described in the above comment, I was able to fix my query by adding an "AND CAST(a.repDate AS DATE) = '20150831'" statement to my query.  I had to explicitly specify the date selected from the second table.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM HourTable t 
INNER JOIN HalfHourTable ht 
  ON CAST(t.repDate AS Date) = CAST(ht.repDate AS Date) 
 AND DATEPART(HOUR, t.repDate) = DATEPART(HOUR, ht.repDate)
```

### Edit

Your query should be

```
SELECT n.repDate
     , n.TA
     , a.batVolt 
FROM [DAP].[dbo].[ARRMet] AS n 
FULL JOIN [DAP].[dbo].[array3] AS a 
ON DATEPART(HOUR, n.repDate) = DATEPART(HOUR, a.repDate) 
AND CAST(n.repDate AS DATE) = CAST(a.repDate AS DATE)
WHERE CAST(n.repDate AS DATE) = '20150831' 
ORDER BY n.repDate DESC
```

Comment: This is what I had tried:


`SELECT n.repDate, n.TA, a.batVolt 
FROM [DAP].[dbo].[ARRMet] AS n
FULL JOIN  [DAP].[dbo].[array3] AS a ON 
(DATEPART(HOUR, n.repDate) = DATEPART(HOUR, a.repDate))
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),n.repDate,110) = '08-31-2015' 
ORDER BY n.repDate DESC`


but this query repeats the value for TA

Comment: compare your query to mine, you have left out the `CAST(t.repDate AS Date) = CAST(ht.repDate AS Date) ` in the ON clause of the join.

Comment: @Mino have a look at my answer I have updated it with a fixed version of your query.

Comment: Yes M.Ali, I had tried it also with the CAST and I get the same behavior.  I have also tried it with your updated query and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: create a sql fiddle and post it here lets see what going on with your query?

Comment: OK, I've created an SQL fiddle and I am getting the expected results here, but not on my server: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1531/4

Very weird.  Any ideas?

Comment: M.Ali, there is nothing wrong with the query.  It runs perfect on SQLFiddle with the subset of my data,  but when I execute the query on my server I get this: 
    [Image](http://i.imgur.com/hTGYMwA.png) 

My tables have 6.5 million rows (array3) and 400 thousand (ARRMet).

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would do this slightly differently than M.Ali. This uses fewer functions and seems a bit simpler to me.

```
SELECT *
FROM HourTable t 
INNER JOIN HalfHourTable ht on
  t.repDate = dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, ht.repDate), 0)
```

Comment: The ON clause is required with the INNER JOIN syntax.

Comment: @PéterSzilvási hahaha right you are. I will update it after only 8 years sitting out there with invalid syntax. :D

Comment: Better late than ever :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use DATEPART()

```
select ta.repDate, ta.code, ta.TA, bat.batVolt
from table2 ta
join table 1 bat
    on (DATEPART(yyyymmddhh,bat.repDate) = DATEPART(yyyymmddhh, ta.repDate)
```

I don't remember exact syntax for datepart but should be something similar to this

Comment: your syntax(first argument) for `DATEPART()` function is wrong!!!! Also you have not taken date into consideration this will result in wrong results too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
SELECT      x.*, y.*
FROM        BatVoltDetails x 
INNER JOIN  TADetails y 
ON LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, x.repDate, 120), 13) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, y.repDate, 120), 13)
```